# Como recuperar parâmetros de uma API do google maps (dentro do IIS) que está fora do projeto ASP.NET- web form

Tags: c#

Utilizo uma API do Google Maps dentro do IIS fora da minha aplicação ASP.NET web form, preciso recuperar as coordenadas e retornar para a pagina anterior do meu projeto.

O problema começa ai, tenho uma 1º pagina com o formulário já preenchido e abaixo do formulário tenho um botão de ("editar"), quando clico nesse botão sou direcionado para a tela de editar que carregaria todos os dados da tela anteior junto com o ícone da Google Maps.

Quando clico no ícone abre o mapa do Google Maps e dentro tem um outro botão de capturar coordenada que, quando clicado, deveria retornar para a pagina de ("Editar"). Porém ele perde os parâmetros apresentado uma mensagem que falta o parâmetro tal...

Já tentei recuperar esse parâmetro pela Session, mas não funciona. Já tentei passar o parâmetro pela URL do Mapa e não funciona, recebo parâmetro = indefinido. Já tentei obter os valores de controles da página fonte no mesmo aplicativo link no site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx) sem sucesso.

Se alguém tiver uma ideia ou outra forma que eu possa resolver esse problema me dê uma dica.

Comment: Inclua o código de como você está fazendo essa consulta e recuperando a informação. Ps.: se são dois sites diferentes e com pools diferentes eles não vão compartilhar a `Session` mesmo...